# Displaying query inside a div

Tags: javascript

Hi Guys I am stuck with my coding. I hope someone can help me with my problem

So I have this class (updateProgress.php) that pulls the value from the DB and process it thru ajax on the other page called data2.php and display the query when user press the show button to the  in (updateProgress.php).

What i have in the data2.php is,

```
<?php
// IF SHOW KEY HAS BEEN PRESSED
if($_POST['action'] == 'show')
    {            
    $sql   = "SELECT * FROM SUB_MASTER_DRAWING
                      WHERE SUB_MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK = '{$_POST["hm"]}'";

    $query = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
            $query_exec = oci_execute($query);

           echo "<table border='1'>";
    while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo '<div id="content">';
                        echo '<table cellspacing = "0"';
                            echo '<tr><th>Head Mark</th>
                                      <th>Cutting</th>
                                      <th>Assembly</th>
                                      <th>Welding</th>
                                      <th>Drilling</th>
                                      <th>Finishing</th>
                                      </tr>';

                            echo "<tr><td><b>$row[HEAD_MARK]/$row[ID]</b></td>";

                                      if ($row['CUTTING'] == 'Y'){                                   
                                          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='cuttingCheckbox'  name='cuttingCheckbox' checked='checked' disabled='disabled'/></td>";
                                      } else {
                                          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='cuttingCheckbox'  name='cuttingCheckbox' onClick='checkboxCheck()' /></td>";                                            
                                      }   
?>
```

So my problem is when user check the checkbox, it should make a query to the database and update the corresponding value. I tried making the javascript function just to check if the checkbox action works on the  outside the php tag but it just doesnt do anything.

is it because i pass all the table query to the  so that it wont process the javascript ?

please help me

Comment: yes what i did is something like this in the header

function checkboxCheck(){
  if(document.cuttingcheckbox.checked == true){
     alert('CHECKBOX CHECKED');
  }
}

Comment: Yeah the method is not firing. I'm trying to find the error now. Even though you don't need it since you have jQuery.

Comment: i guess ajax is the best way. Isnt it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have checkbox with `onClick='checkboxCheck()'` assigned. Just make an ajax call from that javascript function and update whatever value you want from that call. You can create another php file to handle this ajax call.

```
    function checkboxCheck() {
        var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("cuttingCheckbox");

        if (checkbox1.checked) {
            alert('CHECKBOX CHECKED');
        } else {
            alert('CHECKBOX NOT CHECKED');
        }

        // Make Ajax call here, to call a php file
        // which will update the db table
        // You will have to pass other relevant variables like row id etc
    }
```

Comment: So it has to be with ajax ??

because i have variable $row[HEAD_MARK], $row[ID] and $row[CUTTING] to process on the other page. so that means i have to send 3 variables that needs to be passed into the sql query on the other page

Comment: Yes. Ajax is needed because you cannot update db from javascript (checkboxCheck() is a javascript function).

Comment: jaycp thanks for your opinion. So what do you think is the best, sending all the variables to the different page or process the sql inside the ajax ?

Comment: When you check or uncheck `cuttingCheckbox` checkbox, you want to correspondingly set or unset a field in database for that specific row, right ? If yes, then you will have to make an ajax call (I added function from where you can do that). And yes, you will have to pass variables from this ajax call to server, so that you can run your update query on server side script.

Comment: jaycp i could get the ajax working 

   $('#cuttingCheckbox').change(function() {
                    var checkedLength = $(this + ':checked').length;
                    if(1 === checkedLength){
                    alert('checked');
                    } else {
                    alert('unchecked');
                    }
           }); 

But the ajax only happens with the first occurence.

Comment: can you clarify ? you could get ajax working, or is it not working ? please post your entire function code, where you have placed ajax call.

Comment: jaycp, here is the whole code
http://codepad.org/78dT49p3

basically it looks like this 
http://imgur.com/RRrLVqu

and the ajax only works for the first occurence

Comment: Modified your `$('#cuttingCheckbox').change` function. See here http://codepad.org/ykUFRyLb. This will only show an alert. I hope you understand you have to make ajax call from this function.

Comment: i think its basically the same with the previous code i wrote. it still work only for the first occurence. the second and so on... the ajax call doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

That code is ready for a SQL Injection.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I know its vulnerable but I will modify it as long i can get all the functions work

Comment: I think you should re-order your code and apply the MVC pattern. It's a very bad practice mixing the HTML with PHP, and SQL Queries in one file.

Comment: thank you again edwardoyarzun. it takes another step to learn MVC but i will aim for it. thanks

Comment: I've never used ASP.NET
But I recommend you PHP because is free (as in freedom), there are bigger communities to get help, there are more frameworks, is multiplatform, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just using jQuery for handling the clicking of the checkbox:

```
$('#cuttingCheckbox').click(function() { /* function goes here */ });
```

(or use `mousedown` instead of `click`)

And then just have a simple AJAX call to a PHP file. AJAX is really simple and quick with jQuery.